# Login to Netlify-CMS not possible

Tags: authentication, github, netlify-cms, decap-cms

Repository moved to another Github account. Login to Netlify-CMS worked before moving. Push/Pull to Github and Deployment to Vercel work.
But now can't login to Netlify-CMS with Github. URL in Browser and Github settings are correct. I'm even the owner of the app (netlify-cms) in Github settings.  But get a 404 Error in web browser when I'm doing the login: "This is not the web page you are looking for."

Before I tried to login I logged out from Github to avoid using false account. What can I do more?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.